# Does Hindu scripture talk about rights?

Tags: scripture

Does Hindu scripture talk about fundamental rights of humans like right to speak and others ?

Comment: I think such rights are implicitly stated in scriptures.

Comment: It is necessary to rigidly define what you mean by 'right'. For instance, a śiṣya has no right to correct his guru even if his guru is wrong. He must consult a guru greater than that guru and have him do the correction. This would not be in line with the modern understanding that all people have the right to speak.